# Как откатить коммит?

Tags: git

Значит такая ситуация, мне нужно было вернуться назад на несколько коммтов (`git checkout v2.0` не создавая новую ветку), чтоб проверить что то в прошлой версии, потом я забыл про то, что откатился и сделал несколько изменений и закоммитил(`git commit -m 'commit'`), теперь думаю как вырезать этот последний коммит?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD~1` А вообще лучше создавайте бранчи — дёшево и практично!

Comment: @0andriy и что это уберет последний коммит? Просто у меня ситуация, что я нахожусь на ветке мастер, просто откатился на несколько коммитов назад, а теперь мне нужно вернуться обратно вперед, только не оставляя после себя ничего

Comment: `git reset --hard $HASH_TO` , где `$HASH_TO` — это хэш комита, который вам нужен в итоге. Почитайте мануал в конце концов, а?

Answer (score 6):

`git revert [название коммита]` - откатит изменения в виде следующего коммита.
Т.е., создан коммит "Mistake", при использовании revert будет создан еще один коммит "Revert mistake".

Answer (score 2):

Если вам ещё нужны изменения, выполненные в самой последней фиксации*, то
восстановить её можно будет после переключения обратно на нужную ветку. Пока
что нужно запомнить хэш этой фиксации командой `git show --format=%H HEAD`.
Обозначим её вывод как `$HASH`.

Затем просто переключитесь обратно, к предыдущей ветке с помощью `git chechout -`. Если вы попали не туда, куда требовалось, укажите вашу ветку в явном виде.
Кроме того, вы можете увидеть подсказку от git с хэшем фиксации, откуда вы
только что ушли, с предложением создать новую ветку, на неё указывающую.

Затем примените ту самую фиксацию поверх нового состояния командой `git cherry-pick $HASH`. В результате этого, ваши изменения должны оказаться в
нужной вам ветке.

Это же описание, но в виде сценария оболочки.

```
HASH=$(git show --format=%H HEAD)
git checkout -
git cherry-pick $HASH
```

<sub>* [перевод слова commit в контексте ИТ](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=commit&langID=ru-ru)</sub>